# Find repeated words in a string and delete duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a string that contains many words such as:

```
string SetenceString= "red white black white green yellow red red black white"
```

I want to delete all dupplicates and return each word only once:

```
SetenceString= "red white black green yellow"
```

How can I do so with C# ? All help is well appreciated.

Comment: Also PLEASE search on stackoverflow before posting. I can't believe any of the many already existing duplicate questions didn't come up, when you typed this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't even told us what you have tried but..

```
string SetenceString = "red white black white green yellow red red black white";
var result = string.Join(" ", SetenceString.Split(' ').Distinct());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output will be;

> red white black green yellow

But hey, how does that work exactly?

- We split our string with white space to get all your words in a string array.
- We used [`Distinct()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) to get only distinct words in our string array.
- And we used `string.Join` to combine all these distinct words with white space.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer. It's very well explained!

Answer (score 8):

If your words are always  separated:

```
String.Join(" ", SetenceString.Split(' ').Distinct())
```

Else you should rather use regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
    string SetenceString = "red white black white green yellow red red black white";
    string[] data = SetenceString.Split(' ');
    HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        set.Add(data[i]);
    }
```

`set` varible now contains only unique items